# DAM Replication: Access Denied for binaries

Tags: aem

I have a very strange problem on our test environment. We have one author and two identical publish server. For each of the publish server there is a replication agent in place where the "Test connection" works fine. They are identical except the transport URI and are using a replication_receiver user which is set up with the same rights on both publish server.

I imported some content from a different system, containing pages and DAM assets. Then I triggered a "Tree Activation" of the DAM assets. One agent started replicating right away, the other replicated a folder, but then fails at the first image, a JPG. The Exception thrown in the replication log is:

> error: com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationException: Repository error
>   during node import: Access denied.

And a similar error can be found in the error.log:

> POST /bin/receive HTTP/1.1]
>   com.day.cq.replication.impl.servlets.ReplicationServlet Error during
>   replication: Repository error during node import: Access denied.
>   com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationException: Repository error during
>   node import: Access denied.   at
>   com.day.cq.replication.impl.content.durbo.DurboImporter.createNode(DurboImporter.java:269)

It seems the second publish is missing some permissions, but as I said both are identical. We have a content package containing all the technical users and groups together with the base content structure containing the rep:policy nodes.

The only thing I can imagine that someone added some permission on the working publish or removed a permission on the non working one. But I can't find the difference.

Where else than on the node below /content/dam would the replication_receiver user need write access for DAM assets? It was able to create a folder...

Answer (score 0):

Check if it happens with Admin user? If you have some ACLs specific to renditions/assets on publish add the groups in the replicator/transport user you used in you agent configuration.

Comment: This should probably have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I switched to the admin user which worked. Strangely enough, when i switched back to the original user, it worked as well...